How to assign value of dictionary key directly to another variable?
I have a Scripting.Dictionary from which I wish to assign the value of the first key (ie the 0th element in the .Keys array) to aother variable.
I have been unable to do this without first assigning the value of the Keys array to another variable and then accessing the element from that other variable.
How can I do this in one step?
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dict.Add Key:="a", Item:="A"
dict.Add Key:="b", Item:="B"
dict.Add Key:="c", Item:="C"
dict.Add Key:="d", Item:="D"

Dim tmp1
Dim tmp2 As String
tmp1 = dict.Keys
tmp2 = tmp1(0) 'This works


Dim tmp As String
tmp = dict.Keys(0) 'This does not work


The line will work if you use early binding (creating a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and using Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary). Otherwise, you could use tmp = dict.Keys()(0). Note that in a loop, this will be too slow. Also, you could create a loop: Dim Key As Variant: For Each Key In dict.Keys: tmp = Key: Exit For: Next Key.

in VBA "Scripting.Dictionary.keys" property retune an array but you cant directly access an element of this array using the "dict.Keys(0)" , because 'keys' return's  a variant containing an array and you need to explicitly reference that array
Dim tmp AS String

tmp = dict.Keys()(0)

